# how to executing user defined stored procedure using sync up framework

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

My database have 6-7 tables on server side. i want only few 10-50 list of customers which is get me by store procedure (selecting records by joining of 6-7 tables).

I created application(used in both online & offline environment) which is sync up table from server to client vise versa. Which is displaying that customers name in combo box (records from stored procedure).

I am using sync framework. but this 6-7 tables contain huge records near around 67k. I don't want to sync up that 6-7 table. I want to sync up only those list of customer as per the login user.

I created one table like:

```
Customer_List   user_Id   Customer_Name   customer_Id
```

and stored procedure return list of customers as per above table structure:

I want to sync up this table with my stored procedure using sync framework.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

there is on publicly available API in Sync Framework for you to specify/invoke a custom stored proc.

seems like what you're SP does can be represented as a Filter...

e.g., side.CustomerId IN (SELECT CustomerId FROM Customer_List WHERE User_Id =@User_Id)